# Lightbox/Forms Question

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, lightbox

I am trying to allow for the filling out of a form from a lightbox pop up window. One like the one that Get satisfaction uses (though I only need to be able to collect info, not display from a query as well). You can see a Get Satisfaction example at http://tweet.fabeetle.com and clicking the feedback tab.

What is the best way to do this? JQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used http://www.nickstakenburg.com/projects/lightview/ a while back and it worked very well.

Answer (score 0):

bgadoci, if you're not an experienced javascript user (or you are and want to avoid a lot of unnecessary work) you'll definitely want to go with a Javascript library like jQuery. As far as choosing the right plugin, you should shop around while keeping in mind your objective. Some of them will be friendlier with forms where others are built for images only.

I can recommend [colorbox](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/) from experience.

Comment: Thanks man. I used the link that mswebersd provided and seems to be working. Got it all to work so far and now just trying to locate where to put the form info such that is shows in the lightbox.